# Node.js define document object

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Hi i am trying to run a js function on server side using node.js but there is a problem. The function is using document dom to access some hidden values on the returned html and the document is undefined on node.js, is there a way to define the document object?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 11 February 2007), see www.w3.org" />

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="sbb_KoNkmwM" method="post" style="display:none" name="sbb_KoNkmwM">
    <input name='sbb_BQGUL' type='checkbox' value='IbNlk' /><input name='sbb_BQGUL' type=
    'checkbox' value='huTi' /><input name='sbb_BQGUL' type='checkbox' checked="checked"
    value='qGx' /><input name='sbb_BQGUL' type='checkbox' value='WGrkKwxP' /><input name=
    'sbb_BQGUL' type='checkbox' value='tgQHP' /><input name='sbb_BQGUL' type='checkbox'
    value='dDrn' />
  </form>

 function sbb_kVnTj() {
    var data = 'ZmdiRlhjdQ==';
    var rEda = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
    ac = 0,
    dec = "",
    tmp_arr = [];
    do {
        h1 = rEda.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h2 = rEda.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h3 = rEda.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h4 = rEda.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        bits = h1 << 18 | h2 << 12 | h3 << 6 | h4;
        o1 = bits >> 16 & 0xff;
        o2 = bits >> 8 & 0xff;
        o3 = bits & 0xff;
        if (h3 == 64) {
            tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1);
        } else if (h4 == 64) {
            tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2);
        } else {
            tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2, o3);
        }
    } while ( i < data . length );
    dec = tmp_arr.join('');
    return dec.substr(6, 1);

}
function sbb_MHVY() {
    function sbb_iSH(objArr) {
        var ts = '';
        for (i = 0;
....
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.  Are you trying to run the `sbb_kVnTj` function as a server-side function? Also, where are you using `document`? It's not in the code you posted. Please edit your question to include a high-level description of *what* you want to do and *how* you are trying to achieve it.

Comment: @apsillers Ups sorry, the returned javascript and ids are random, it is a protection. Yes i am trying to run sbb_kVnTj which is also a name randomly created, it will return a character and it includes some document.getgetElementById() requesting different ids at different times. So there is no reasonable workarround but run it as javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are ways to create documents in Node. For example you can look at `jsdom`: https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom.

Comment: jsdom has very limited capability as compared to actual DOM Object.